# Finding parameter from inverse relations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

$ x,y,z$ are known functions of $t$ and  $f$ is a known function:
$$ z(t)= f ( x(t),y(t)) ; $$

In order to compute $t$ as a function of $x$(or other dependent variables) how to define some differential equation as 
$$ \frac{dt}{dx}= F (x,y,z,t)$$

or in any other suitable differential equation form to find $t$ as a dependent variable ?